# Java - Return either a single or two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

Either create a 1-D array or 2-D array based on the integer value passed. The task can be implemented as shown with the code below but uses `Object` type to store and return either types. This *seems* to be a poor coding practice especially because a cast is required every time a value needed to be accessed from the array. I hope there is a cleaner approach to this.

The last request is that the `getArray` method doesn't perform any checking and returns the variable itself (*i.e.,* `return info;`) and `instanceof` (if used) will be used only once, not every time a value needs to be accessed.

```java
public class MultiArrayType {
    private Object info;//can be either a 1-D or 2-D array

    public MultiArrayType(int x) {
        if (x > 10) {
            info = new long[x][x];
        } else {
            info = new long[x];
        }
    }

    public Object getArray() {
        return info;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MultiArrayType t = new MultiArrayType(7);
        Object array = t.getArray();

        if (array instanceof long[]) {
            System.out.println("1D array");
            System.out.println("Index zero is: " + ((long[]) array)[0]);
        } else if (array instanceof long[][]) {
            System.out.println("2D array");
            System.out.println("Cell (0, 0) is: " + ((long[][]) array)[0][0]);
        } else {
            //for safety only :)
            System.out.println("Some other unknown object");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe to use generics

Comment: @SergeyZh., can you please elaborate further? How can I initialize my T type object as a 1-D/2-D array?

Comment: `int[]` and `int[][]` are different types with no common supertype (aside from `Object`), hence storing it as `Object` seems the only choice. I would rather question the whole approach to either return a 1-D or a 2-D array.